# How To read Emails in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, email

How can I read Emails in vb.net 2005 (without Using Third Party Control). Please Any idea and source code Give to me.(Any Method)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough - what format/location are the emails in?  A POP3 mailbox?  local text/mime files?

Answer (score 5):

First of all there are multiple protocols to retreive mail:

POP3, IMAP, etc...

I suggest you start by familiarizing yourself with the various
components that make up an e-mail system.

- Mail Transfer Agent (Protocol: SMTP)
- Mail Delivery Agent (Protocols: POP3, IMAP)
- Mail User Agent (Outlook, Webmail, Thunderbird, your application)

Basically what you are trying to write is a Mail User Agent.
A mail user agent has to "fetch" the mails from a Mail Delivery Agent using
either POP or IMAP.

This means you will have to learn about these two protocols:

POP3 RFC: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1939.html

IMAPv4 RFC: http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt

Since e-mail communication happens using TCP/IP you will have to learn
how to use the classes in the System.Net.Sockets namespace.

Take a look at the TcpClient class: http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt

Try to understand these concepts first and then I suggest you start out with POP3,
this protocol is quite easy. If you have problems then with very specific TcpClient code please update your question or post a new question.

Hope this sets you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to connect to POP mailbox and download emails, I'm afraid it's not all that straightforward to do in VB.NET.

There is [an extensive article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/QMailClient.aspx) but it looks like a fairly advanced.